# Run a war file in command Prompt using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have to deploy a war file in a location in `D:\Temp\$todaydate` in command prompt as Admin using PowerShell, so my command should open the cmd prompt as admin in path `D:\Temp\$todaydate` run Javapath "\apps\wsserver\9.0\base\java\8.0\bin\jar.exe" -cvf foo.war`

I have tried using `Start-Process -Verb "RunAs"` but since I am new to PowerShell I couldn't finish the code

```
Start-Process -java "jar.exe" -ArgumentList "/K cd /d D:\temp\$todaydate" -Verb "runas"
```

Comment: What is the output of `Start-Process "D:\Temp\$todaydate\apps\9.0\base\java\jar.exe" -ArgumentList "-cvf foo.war" -Verb "runas"` ?

Comment: If the folder is actually called `$todaydate` and thats not a variable, you'll need to use single quotes as otherwise PowerShell will be trying to expand it as a variable. E.g `Start-Process -java "jar.exe" -ArgumentList '/K cd /d D:\temp\$todaydate' -Verb "runas"`

Comment: @AdminOfThings the output is 10-11 files unzipped as result of the war file

Answer (score 0):

My guess `$todayDate` shall be the actual date. You can try to use the call operator (&) to invoke Java.

```
$d =((get-date).ToShortDateString()) 
$dashDate = $d -replace "/", "-"
$dPath ="D:/temp/$dashDate" 
New-Item $dPath - ErrorAction SilentlyContinoue
Push-Location
Set-Location $dPath
# Use absolute path to Java.exe and war file in below statement 
& "java.exe -cvf foo.war" 
Pop-Location
```

If you need to resolve variable names when calling Java use [invoke-expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6) instead the call operator.

[Call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#call-operator-):

> Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that are stored in variables and represented by strings or script blocks.

Comment: Hi @Moerwald my java location is "D\apps\wsserver\9.0\base\java\8.0\bin\jar.exe" and my war file is in the location "D\Temp\$dashdate" I tried using the command   $warjvm=Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" $runjar -ArgumentList "-jar $rgnwar .\*" -RedirectStandardOutput "Error.txt" where $runjar is java path $rgnwar location of war in "D\Temp\$dashdate"